# Need help fixing ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Tags: python

I am a newbie in python, so maybe it is a simple task. However, I am getting a little frustrated here... Here is the thing:

I defined this function in Pyhton:

```
def arrays():
    """
    returns to 2 sets of 3d coordinates
    """
    x1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    y1 = [110.0,110.0,110.0,110.0,110.0]
    z1 = [200.0,160.0,120.0,80.0 ,40.0 ]

    x2 = [60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0 ]
    y2 = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
    z2 = [200.0,160.0,120.0,80.0 ,40.0 ]

    well1 = [x1,y1,z1]
    well2 = [x2,y2,z2]
    return well1,well2
```

and now, when executing the following code, I get

```
>>> well1,well2=arrays()
>>> for xs,ys,zs in [well1,well2]:
...     print(xs)
...     for i,j,k in [xs,ys,zs]:
...         print(i,j,k)
... 
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

How can't I print these values? What is the appropriate syntax here?
I wasn't able to find anything that helps me fix this issue. Can anybody give a hand? It will be much appreciated! Cheers

Comment: What is desired output? I assume you want to print something like `0.0, 110.0, 200.0` in the first case?

Comment: What output would like to get? xs, ys, and zs are lists. Would you like to output them as lists, or their elements?

Comment: @Vitalii Indeed, that is what I am looking at. To retrieve xs[0],ys[0],z[0], then xs[1],ys[1],z[1], and so on. In individual values, I,j, and k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raised error comes from internal loop:

```
for i,j,k in [xs,ys,zs]:
```

The problem is each element of the list will be unpacked. And each of your elements (`xs, ys,zs`) have 5 elements inside.

In a simple example, during unpacking you should have same amount of elements both in left and right sides. This means that if your `xs` has 5 elements, your should have 5 variables on the left side:

```
i,j,k,a,b = xs
```

Thus, your code raises exception because you have only 3 variables on the left side.

**Solution**

I suppose that you want to output something like this: `0.0, 110.0, 200.0`. In this case you should try using [zip function](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/)

```
for xs,ys,zs in well1,well2:
    print(xs)
    for i,j,k in zip(xs,ys,zs):
        print(i,j,k)

[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
0.0 110.0 200.0
0.0 110.0 160.0
0.0 110.0 120.0
0.0 110.0 80.0
0.0 110.0 40.0
[60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0]
60.0 0.0 200.0
60.0 0.0 160.0
60.0 0.0 120.0
60.0 0.0 80.0
60.0 0.0 40.0
```